# iOS / Swift 3: UIView too big within UIPageController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I embedded a PageController within a ContainerView. 
Why are the Views I display in the PageController not scaled to fit the PageController? How can I achieve "scale to fit"?
(At least the PageController itself adapts its size to the ContainerView)

My classes are:

```
import UIKit

class YellowController : UIViewController

{

}

class GreenController : UIViewController
{

}

//from a tutorial:
class PageController : UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate
{
// from stackoverflow to avoid the black box at the bottom of the pagecontroller
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    for view in self.view.subviews
    {
        if view is UIScrollView
        {
            view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        }
        else
        {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}


lazy var VCArray: [UIViewController] =
{
    return [self.VCInstance(name: "InfoPage"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "FragePage"),
            self.VCInstance(name: "AntwortPage") ]
}()

private func VCInstance (name: String) -> UIViewController
{
    let VCC = UIStoryboard(name: "Lerneinheit", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)

    return VCC
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.dataSource = self
    self.delegate = self
    if let InfoPage = VCArray.first
    {
        setViewControllers([InfoPage], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}


public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: viewController)
    else
    {
        return nil
    }

    if (viewControllerIndex<1)
    {
        return nil
    }

    return VCArray[viewControllerIndex - 1]
}
public func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
{
    guard let viewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: viewController)
        else
    {
        return nil
    }

    if viewControllerIndex == VCArray.count-1
    {
        return nil
    }

    return VCArray[viewControllerIndex + 1]
}

public func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{
    return VCArray.count
}

public func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
{
    guard let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first, let firstViewControllerIndex = VCArray.index(of: firstViewController)
    else
    {
        return 0
    }

    return firstViewControllerIndex
}
```

IB: 
[image: IB]
Result wth the yellow view beeing cut instead of scaled to fit the PageController:
[image: Result wth the yellow view beeing cut instead of scaled to fit the PageController]
Constraints for the yellow view:
[image: Constraints for the yellow view]

Comment: You will need to provide more data.
Does the "Two Controller" is in fact contains a scroll view which is embedded inside the label ?
Do you use auto layout correctly ?
How do you "feed" the VC's to the UIPage ?
Providing a snip codes will be helpful

Comment: Does your txtInfo is scrollable inside that VC ?  Also, looks like you have a greyed out constraint, deleted it please.

Comment: Yes, it's scrollable.

Comment: So you added a textview and you complain why is it scrollable ?

Comment: Problem is, the yellow views size is not adjusted to the PageControllers size. It's not a problem of the TextField.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your issue.
I'd start with removing the viewDidLayoutSubviews. No idea why you did it, I don't see "black box" in my storyboard

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: Added the relevant answer (If it's actually is the answer..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is redundant, remove it:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    for view in self.view.subviews
    {
        if view is UIScrollView
        {
            view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
        }
        else
        {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
}
```